# rsync unexpected tag 93

Tags: c, linux, rsync

I have to use to rsync to align software between 2 boards on a shelf.
On the server side, rsync daemon is running and on client side, I'm using the following instruction (in C language):

```
sprintf(cmd,"rsync -avh /full.tgz root@172.16.1.5::/sw_release
system(cmd);
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
When it doesn't work, server reports the following error:

> " an unexpected tag 93 and protocol errors in io.c at line 1169"

If I execute the command directly on shell :

```
rsync -avh /full.tgz root@172.16.1.5::/sw_release
```

it always works.

I found a [post about the same error](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2009-January/022455.html)
but it seems to me that nobody gave the solution.

Could you please tell if you have ever seen such error?
And if you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrongly the command I'm using:sprintf(cmd,"rsync -avh /full.tgz root@172.16.1.5::/sw_release"); system(cmd);

Comment: try with `fork` and [execv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv)

Comment: Here is a post with a similar error (seems the number after the tag does not really tell much), where possible reasons are discussed: http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/unexpected-tag-55-td2503327.html

Comment: Thank you both Bolov and Nlu. I'll try with fork and execv even if I'd expect system works. About the post suggested by Nlu it's very interesting. I have the suspect that my remote shell corrupts the data  Infact in order to understand much more I increased verbosity on remote side logging on a file (rsync  --log-file=/var/log/rsync.log -vvv ... ) and I am not able to reproduce the issue

Comment: Is it possible that creating the log file, the shell doesn't add extra characters to the data stream? Sorry if my question is stupid, but it's the first time I use system() function. Thanks